# Getting error on python: TypeError: '(0, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

For anyone wondering what to do when they receive this error:
It is due to using numpy commands on pandas dataframes, to solve this error you need to convert pandas dataframes you're using to numpy with the "dataframeName".to_numpy() command.

My program below shows and outlines where you need to do this for anyone that gets stuck on this problem.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

fileDir = Path("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test") #Configures the file path directory
excelFiles = fileDir.rglob('*.csv*') #Sets the directory to the file extension .csv
n_1=len(list(excelFiles)) #Count the number of folders in directory
outfile = Path(fileDir, 'OUT.csv')
fileNames = sorted(fileDir.glob('*.csv'))

second_col= []

for file in fileNames:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    second_col.append(df.iloc[:, 1])

matrix = np.array(second_col)
np.savetxt(outfile, matrix, delimiter=",")


#######
folder_walk = os.walk(fileDir)
first_file_in_folder = next(folder_walk)[2][0]
Wave_data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test/"+first_file_in_folder, header=None)
Wave_data_appendix=Wave_data.T
Wave_data_final=Wave_data_appendix.to_numpy() #ADD THIS LINE OF CODE
n_2=len(Wave_data_appendix.columns)

#Transposing the OUT.csv file
main=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test/OUT.csv', header=None)
transposed_main=main.T
transposed_main_final=transposed_main.to_numpy() #ADD THIS LINE OF CODE

#Below combines the matrix together
Reshaped=np.reshape(np.append(Wave_data_final[0,:],transposed_main_final),(n_1,n_2)) #Error on this line unknown
```

This line of code:

```
Reshaped=np.reshape(np.append(Wave_data_appendix[0,:],transposed_main),(n_1,n_2)) #Error on this line unknown
```

Generates this long message in the source when running the program.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Jonas\Downloads\translation.py", line 41, in 
Reshaped=np.reshape(np.append(Wave_data_appendix[0,:],transposed_main),(n_1,n_2)) #Error on this line unknown

File "C:\Users\Jonas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in **getitem**
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

File "C:\Users\Jonas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 353, in get_loc
return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

File "C:\Users\Jonas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(key)

File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 116, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

TypeError: '(0, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key.

Hope this helps for anyone.

Comment: `.iloc[0,:]` 72, 73 help here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position

Comment: `Wave_data_appendix[0,:]` is valid indexing for a 2d numpy array.  But the error traceback indicates the object is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: The python interpreter translates the `[0,:]` indexing to  indexing with `'(0, slice(None, None, None))'`

Comment: Hi all, I've solved the problem by changing the pandas format to numpy. All I did was Wave_final=Wave_data_appendix_to.numpy(). And then did this with the other pandas object.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the problem into parts:

First compute:

```
wrk = np.append(Wave_data_appendix[0,:], transposed_main)
```

Then print its shape (for diagnostics).
Print also *n_1* and *n_2*, maybe also shapes of *Wave_data_appendix*
and *transposed_main*.

And the last point is to compute *Reshaped*:

```
Reshaped = np.reshape(np.append(wrk, (n_1, n_2))
```

The above advice will probably not solve your problem, but at least
you will have more information, guiding you to the actuaol solution.

Comment: Hi I've solved the problem by changing the pandas format to numpy. All I did was Wave_final=Wave_data_appendix_to.numpy(). And then did this with the other pandas object.